# Transform list with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a list that has elements in this form,the strings may change but the formats stay similar:

```
["Radio0","Tether0","Serial0/0","Eth0/0","Eth0/1","Eth1/0","Eth1/1","vlanX","modem0","modem1","modem2","modem3","modem6"]
```

I would like to transform it to the list below. You can see it would remove copies of the same occurrence of a string such as Eth - just having one occurrence in the new list and transforms numbers into x and y to be more generic:

```
["RadioX","TetherX","SerialX/Y","EthX/Y","vlanX","modemX"]
```

I am messing around with different regex's and my method is quite messy, would be interested in any elegant solutions you guys think of.

Here is some code for it that could be improved on, also set does not preserve order so that should be improved too:

```
a = ["Radio0","Tether0","Serial0/0","Eth0/0","Eth0/1","Eth0/2","Eth1/0","vlanX","modem0","modem1","modem2","modem3","modem6"]
c =[]
for i in a:
     b = re.split("[0-9]", i)
     if "/" in i:
         c.append(b[0]+"X/Y")
     elif len(b) > 1:
         c.append(b[0]+"X")
     else:
         c.append(b)
print set(c)

set(['modemX', 'TetherX', 'RadioX', 'vlanX', 'SerialX/Y', 'EthX/Y'])
```

Possible improvement on set for preserving order:

```
unique=[]
[unique.append(item) for item in c if item not in unique]
print unique

['RadioX', 'TetherX', 'SerialX/Y', 'EthX/Y', 'vlanX', 'modemX']
```

Comment: my method is non regex one, interested?

Comment: @harshil9968 yes of course, i would jsut like to see different ways to do it.

Comment: It took me some time to understand what you wanted to do, you migth be able to clarify the question.

Comment: @Sayse It also removes copies, so tehre would be only one Eth entry, one Modem entry etc

Comment: @Pierre.Sassoulas I will try and clarify, thanks

Comment: @Sayse I loop through the list and use re.split to separate the letters from numbers, then I test the length of the second element to see if I should use X or X or X/Y. I then have to check if there are multiple occurrences of the same thing (multiple EthX/Y) and remove the others.

Comment: Well I had something too so this is disapointing. I used re.match("(?P<captured_text>\W)*[\d]?[/]?[\d]?", spam). Good luck !

Comment: @Jan Nearly right, misses the /Y aspect. i also want to preserve order, but great answer thanks!

Comment: **Five** lines, guys: http://ideone.com/816bFL

Comment: @Paul: Updated, see demo on ideone.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re


def particular_case(string):
    return re.sub("\d+", "X", re.sub("\d+/\d+", "X/Y", w))


def generic_case(string, letters=['X', 'Y', 'Z']):
    len_letters = len(letters)
    list_matches = list(re.finditer(r'\d+', string))
    result, last_index = "", 0

    if len(list_matches) == 0:
        return string

    for index, match in enumerate(list_matches):
        result += string[last_index:
                         match.start(0)] + letters[index % len_letters]
        last_index = match.end(0)

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    words = ["Radio0", "Tether0", "Serial0/0", "Eth0/0", "Eth0/1", "Eth1/0",
             "Eth1/1", "vlanX", "modem0", "modem1", "modem2", "modem3", "modem6"]

    result = []
    result2 = []

    for w in words:
        new_value = particular_case(w)

        if new_value not in result:
            result.append(new_value)

        new_value = generic_case(w)

        if new_value not in result2:
            result2.append(new_value)

    print result
    print result2
```

Comment: Thanks, this is better. Glad it's opened again to see peoples answers.

Comment: @Paul Indeed, this answer already meet your requirements. But even so, can you think of any additional cases you need to deal with?

Comment: looks good as is because \d+ covers all length numbers, and it looks nicer than mine. Cheers.

Comment: @Paul Ok, I've decided to edit again and provide you a more complete answer for the sake of completeness. This one provides the solution for your simple particular case and also for a generic one, hope that helps. Interesting question btw, it was fun ;-)

Comment: Great stuff, I love these kinds of little problems too, and to see what people come up with.

Answer (score 2):

The following code should be general enough to allow for up to 3 numbers in the strings, but you can simply change the *repl* variable to allow for more.

```
import re

elements = ["Radio0","Tether0","Serial0/0","Eth0/0","Eth0/1","Eth1/0","Eth1/1","vlanX","modem0","modem1","modem2","modem3","modem6"]
repl = "XYZ"

for i in range(len(repl)):
    elements = [re.sub("[0-9]",repl[i], element, 1) for element in elements]

result = set(elements)
```

Comment: Very nice solution. You could even save one line by doing a set comprehension instead of a list comprehension.

Comment: You are right, I haven't thought about that. On the other hand, then it would be quite difficult to read for many people (including me :) ).

Answer (score 1):

I used [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) to find and replace all numbers:

```
def repl(string):
    #use regex to find all numbers
    numbers= re.finditer(r'\d+', string)

    #replace the numbers with letters. zip will stop when the sequence of
    #numbers OR letters runs out.
    for match, char in zip(numbers, 'XYZ'): #add more characters if necessary
        string= string[:match.start()] + char + string[match.end():]
    return string

s= set() #set to keep track of duplicates while maintaining order
result= []
for string in l:
    string= repl(string)
    if string in s: #ignore if duplicate
        continue

    #otherwise add to result list
    s.add(string)
    result.append(string)
```

This can replace up to 3 numbers with `X`, `Y` or `Z` can easily be modified to support more.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for:

```
import re

rx = r'\d+'
incoming = ["Radio0","Tether0","Serial0/0","Eth0/0","Eth0/1","Eth1/0","Eth1/1","vlanX","modem0","modem1","modem2","modem3","modem6"]

outgoing = []
for item in incoming:
    t = re.sub(rx, 'X', item)
    if t not in outgoing:
        outgoing.append(t)
print(outgoing)
# ['RadioX', 'TetherX', 'SerialX/X', 'EthX/X', 'vlanX', 'modemX']
```

Or (just another syntax example with the help of the so powerful `Python` list comprehensions):

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'\d+')
incoming = ["Radio0","Tether0","Serial0/0","Eth0/0","Eth0/1","Eth1/0","Eth1/1","vlanX","modem0","modem1","modem2","modem3","modem6"]

def cleanitem(item):
    return rx.sub('X', item)

outgoing = []
[outgoing.append(item) \
    for item in (cleanitem(x) for x in incoming) \
    if item not in outgoing]
print(outgoing)
```

---

See [**a working demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/l0Wist).

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
import functools

lst = ["Radio0","Tether0","Serial0/0","Eth0/0","Eth0/1","Eth1/0","Eth1/1","vlanX","modem0","modem1","modem2","modem3","modem6"]

def process_str(s, letters='XY'):
    return functools.reduce(lambda txt, letter: re.sub(r'\d+', letter, txt, 1), letters, s)

r = set(map(process_str, lst))
print(r)
```